# Why does Python RotatingFileHandler's "maxBytes " not work

Tags: python, logging, python-logging

I'm trying to do a test run of the `logging` module's RotatingFileHandler as follows:

```
from logging import getLogger, Formatter
from logging.handlers import RotatingFileHandler

MAX_LOG_SIZE = 2000

_null = lambda *s: None
LOG_FORMAT = '%(process)d [%(name)s %(asctime)s] %(levelname)s: %(message)s'

class Logger(object):
    __slots__ = '_Logger__logger'

    def __init__(self, name='main'):
        self.__logger = getLogger(name)
        if not self.__logger.handlers:
            self.add_handler(name)

    def add_handler(self, name):

        file_name = 'log.log'
        handler = RotatingFileHandler(file_name, 'a+', MAX_LOG_SIZE)
        handler.setFormatter(Formatter(LOG_FORMAT))
        self.__logger.addHandler(handler)
        self.__logger._file_name = file_name

    def ERROR(self, msg, *args):
        self.__logger.error(msg, *args, **{})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    logger = Logger()
    for i in range(1000):
        logger.ERROR('logger.content')
```

However, with MAX_LOG_SIZE = 2000, the resulting of log.log file contains too much data large than 2000 bytes

How can I limit max size of the logfile?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to read the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html#rotatingfilehandler) more carefully: you are missing the kwargs `maxBytes` and `backupCount`.

Replace this

```
handler = RotatingFileHandler(file_name, 'a+', MAX_LOG_SIZE)
```

for this

```
handler = RotatingFileHandler(file_name, 'a+', maxBytes=MAX_LOG_SIZE, backupCount=5)
```

Notice you shall set a `backupCount` value that fits your needs, I just used a random one.

A further explanation of why your piece of code does not roll the file is because the value `backupCount` is 0. See the following:

> You can use the maxBytes and backupCount values to allow the file to
>   rollover at a predetermined size. When the size is about to be
>   exceeded, the file is closed and a new file is silently opened for
>   output. Rollover occurs whenever the current log file is nearly
>   maxBytes in length; **but if either of maxBytes or backupCount is zero,
>   rollover never occurs,** so you generally want to set backupCount to at
>   least 1, and have a non-zero maxBytes.

Comment: I just wanted to add this bit from the documentation as I noticed your example is missing maxBytes: "Rollover occurs whenever the current log file is nearly maxBytes in length; but if either of maxBytes or backupCount is zero, rollover never occurs, so you generally want to set backupCount to at least 1, and have a non-zero maxBytes." I was getting a blank log backup until I specified a maxBytes.