# How to split python logs into multiple files if the log file exceeds a certain limit?

Tags: python, file, logging, file-handling, python-logging

I have already tried the `RotatingFileHandler`, That solution is not what I am looking for. I want a system that will automatically split log file into multiple files if it exceeds a certain limit (ex 10MB).

Already tried this, but this is not what I want.

```
my_handler = RotatingFileHandler(log_filename, mode='a', maxBytes=1024*1024*10, backupCount=2, encoding=None, delay=0)
```

Actually Rotating file handler has a rollover thing, which makes the logs neverending but not unlimited. What I mean to say, if my logs cross a certain limit (both files and size), the logs which were taken in the beginning get omitted/deleted.

I know I can simply increase the file size and backup number, but again there is a **limit**. Which I do not want.

Comment: Why is it not what you want? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40088496/how-to-use-pythons-rotatingfilehandler

Comment: This might be interesting too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48095578/why-does-python-rotatingfilehandlers-maxbytes-not-work/48095853

Comment: Actually Rotating file handler has a rollover thing, which makes the logs neverending but not unlimited. What I mean to say, if my logs cross a certain limit (both files and size), the logs which were taken in the beginning get omitted/deleted.

Comment: This is the reason why I want a simple system that takes a neverending and unlimited amount of logs, it should simply split the log file into multiple files if it exceeds a certain limit.

Comment: Why can't you subclass RotatingFileHandler and add the behaviour changes in your subclass?

Comment: Got a solution that splits the file but do not rotate them?